# Is there any more elegant way to reduce this positive/negative logic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

Is there any more elegant way to reduce the code below, which should reverse a direction from left to right and vice versa, based on the size of a line?

```
if right_length > left_length:
    direction = -1
elif right_length < left_length:
    direction = 1
else:
    direction = 0
```

Comment: Python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp ?

Comment: @G_M, sorry, I corrected the question, it's for Python 3.

Comment: Maybe `numpy.sign` is an option (using `left_length - right_length`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
def direction(right_length, left_length):
    diff = left_length - right_length
    return int(abs(diff) / diff) if diff else 0

print(direction(5, 10)) # 1
print(direction(10, 5)) # -1
print(direction(1, 1)) # 0
```

Comment: I consider this the most elegant since it does not depend on other libraries and in the same way it leaves the logic separate from the main code, resulting in a simpler and more intuitive code. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to explicitly  check for `== 0` here, just use `return 0 if not diff else int(abs(diff) / diff)` or `return int(abs(diff) / diff) if diff else 0` both of which are shorter yet still very readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce 3 branching statements to 2 if you use the [`math.copysign`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.copysign) function:

```
import math
direction = 0 if left == right else math.copysign(1, left - right)
```

`copysign` will copy the sign of `left - right` and apply it to the left operand (in this case, 1).

If `left` and `right` are floats, use `math.isclose` to check for closeness accounting for floating inaccuracies.

```
direction = 0 if math.isclose(left, right) else math.copysign(1, left - right)
```

---

If you have numpy, you can handle the special case of `left == right` with the function itself using [`np.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html):

```
import numpy as np
direction = np.sign(left - right)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use print with two conditional expressions

```
print(1 if r_len > l_len else -1 if l_len > r_len else 0)
```

Comment: This answer does not contain a generator function. It's just using two conditional expressions.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry mis-phrased that

Answer (score 1):

A compact and elegant function definition, if you need to reuse the code, could be this:

```
f = lambda x,y: 1 if x<y else -1 if x>y else 0

direction = f(right_length, left_length)
```

Comment: Thank you! And Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You need the `cmp` (compare) function from the `math` package.  In other languages, a similar function is called `sign`.  The Python community didn't have a clear consensus on edge cases, and has so far left `sign` out of the language.

```
direction = cmp(left_length, right_length)
```

I think this got deprecated in Python 3.  In that case, use `numpy.sign`

For Python 3 *without* `numpy`, you could do

```
diff = left_length - right_length
print (math.copysign(1, diff) if diff else 0)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'cmp'`?

Comment: @coldspeed: Thanks ... I left some garbage in my sandbox.

Comment: "sorry, I corrected the question, it's for Python 3."